# Proving that $y$-component of the electric field of a uniformly charged ring is zero without using symmetry

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics

It seems this case is always worked out by means of symmetry in standar Physics textbooks: arguing that for any two opposite segments in the ring, their perpendicular electric field components cancel each other. If the magnitude of the electric field of a small charge dq is:

$$dE=k\frac {dq}{x^2+a^2}$$

Then the $y$-component is:

$$dE_y=k\frac {dq}{x^2+a^2}\sin \theta$$

And the question is, how has this expression to be integrated in order to get zero?

[image: Problem image]

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to show without symmetry that the components go to zero, you need to write out the components using the unit-vector associated with the direction of $d\vec{E}$. This can be done by noticing that the vector connecting the element of charge and the point of interest also points in the same direction as $d\vec{E}$. Therefore, we can construct the unit-vector of $d\vec{E}$ from $\vec{r}$, the vector the points from the element of charge and the point of interest. The figure draw below is to allow you to see how I am generating the vector $\vec{r}$, which you can think of as the blue line.

[image]

So,

$$\vec{r}=\left<x-0,0-a\cos(\phi),0-a\sin(\phi)\right>=\left<x,-a\cos(\phi),-a\sin(\phi)\right>$$

The unit-vector is obtained by dividing by the magnitude of $\vec{r}$, which is
$$r=\sqrt{x^2+(-a\cos(\phi))^2+(-a\sin(\phi))^2}=\sqrt{x^2+a^2}$$

So,

$$\hat{r}=\left<\frac{x}{x^2+a^2},-\frac{a\cos(\phi)}{x^2+a^2},-\frac{a\sin(\phi)}{x^2+a^2}\right>$$

Writing out $d\vec{E}$ fully, we get

$$d\vec{E}=k\frac{dq}{r^2}\hat{r}=k\frac{dq}{x^2+a^2}\left<\frac{x}{x^2+a^2},-\frac{a\cos(\phi)}{x^2+a^2},-\frac{a\sin(\phi)}{x^2+a^2}\right>$$

or

$$d\vec{E}=\left<k\frac{xdq}{\left(x^2+a^2\right)^{3/2}},-k\frac{adq\cos(\phi)}{\left(x^2+a^2\right)^{3/2}},-k\frac{adq\sin(\phi)}{\left(x^2+a^2\right)^{3/2}}\right>$$

Since the ring is a 1-dimensional object, we can associate it with

$$\lambda=\frac{dq}{dl}$$

or

$$dq=\lambda dl$$

And since the element $dl$ is just a section of the ring,

$$dl=ad\phi$$

The rest is just integrating the ring and you can see that the y-component and the z-component goes to zero because we are integrating $\sin(\phi)$ and $\cos(\phi)$ through a full period.

Comment: Good derivation but you do not need to do the y and z component integration from $\phi=0$ to $\phi=2\pi$. Take two elements with $\phi$ separation $\pi$ and use $\cos (\phi+\pi)= -\cos \phi$ and $\sin(\phi+\pi)= -\sin\phi$ to produce $d\vec E= \langle....,0,0\rangle$ and for the x component integrate from $\phi=0$ to $\phi = \pi$. Symmetry via Maths.

Answer (score 0):

$$dE_{y}=k\frac{dq}{x^2+a^2}\sin\theta$$

Assume $\sigma$ is linear charge density.So, $dq=\sigma\ dx$

From the figure given,

$$\sin\theta=\frac{x}{(x^2+a^2)^{1/2}}$$

Putting the value of $\sin\theta$ and $dq$,

$$dE_{y}= k\sigma \frac{x\ dx}{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+a^2)^{1/2}}$$

As $y$-component is varying from $-a$ to $+a$,

so integrating it from $-a$ to $+a$, we get,

$$\int_{-a}^{+a}dE_{y}=k\sigma\int_{-a}^{+a}\frac{x\ dx}{(x^2+a^2)^{3/2}}$$

Take $x^2+a^2=t\implies2x\ dx=da$, and solving we get,

$$E_{y}=k\sigma\left[-\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x^2+a^2)}}\right]_{-a}^{+a}$$

So, $E_{y}= 0$

Comment: I believe $sin(\theta)=\frac{a}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}. Unless my eyes are playing tricks on me.

Comment: That's correct for parallel component..but,for perpendicular component, it's $(90-\theta)$...For clarity, I'm writing $\theta^{'}$ instead of $\theta$ .So, for y-component, $sin{\theta^{'}}=sin(90-\theta)=cos\theta=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x²+a²}}$